# Varnish Cache Exclude /forums/ directory

Tags: caching, varnish

I am having a problem with varnish cache, trying to get it to not cache the following directory /forums/ on my server as its causing conflict with the forum software.  I used the below code in my default.vcl but I am unable to get varnish to restart.

i changed example.com to my website, i just dont want varnish to cache example.com/forums/

```
sub vcl_recv
{

# Do not cache forums
if (req.http.host ~ "example.com" ||
req.url ~ "^/forums" ||
{
return (pass);
```

Answer (score 2):

Corrected code:

```
sub vcl_recv
{

# Do not cache forums
if (req.http.host == "example.com" || req.url ~ "^/forums")
{
return (pass);
}
}
```